# Couldn't pass a function as props to child component with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a parent component with a state and a setState in a function, then the state and function is passed to child component inorder to get values (input field is in child component). So, when the function is called in the child component, parent component updates the state.
function : The function get four arguments when called in the child component i.e the values to set the state.

parent :

```
export interface IState {
  people: {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    description:string,
    note ?: string 
  }[]
}

class App extends React.Component<IState["people"]> {
  state  = [
    {
      name : "",
      age : 0,
      description: "",
      note: ""
  }
]

 handleState = (name: string,age : number,description : string,note ?: string) => {
  this.setState({
    name: name,
    age: age,
    description : description,
    note : note 
  })
}


  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      <h1> List of People </h1>
      <List people={this.state} />
      <AddToList people={this.state}  handleState={this.handleState}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child :

```
class AddToList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name : "",
        description : "",
        age: "",
        note:""
    }
    render(){
    const handleChange = (e : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    [e.target.name] : [e.target.value]
})
        }
        const handleClick = () => {
            if(!this.state.name || !this.state.description || !this.state.age ){
                return 
            }

            this.props.handleState()
        }
        return (
            <div className="AddToList">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={handleChange} name={"name"}/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="description" value={this.state.description} onChange={handleChange} name={"description"}/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="age" value={this.state.age} onChange={handleChange} name={"age"}/>
                <textarea placeholder="note" value={this.state.note} onChange={handleChange} name="note"/>
                <button onClick ={handleClick}>Add</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Error :
**`Property 'handleState' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.`**

Comment: Please check out my comment, it should help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you create interfaces for components that are getting any props. In App component you don't get any so why did you add it there?
You pass `handleState` function to `AddToList` component so you should add interface there with all values:

```
interface AddToListProps {
    handleState: (name: string,age : number,description : string,note ?:string) => void
}
```

and later add it to `AddToList`.

Answer (score 1):

You need add type for props `handleState` in `AddToList` component

```
class AddToList extends React.Component <{handleState: (name: string,age : number,description : string,note ?: string) => void}> {}
```